# Regular expression for string starting on "01" with length 11

Tags: c#, regex

In my model class, I have a property called `ContactNo`. I want a regular expression for validation purposes. It should validate that the property starts with "01" and has 11 characters, all numerical.

Comment: You do not need a regex for that. Check numeric with `.All(p => Char.IsDigit(p))`, `01` with `.StartsWith("01")` and length with `.Length == 11`. You can even set different error messages with this approach.

Comment: You should checkout this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation) and its answers, if true it is on the tangent of your question, it should be helpful to you

Answer (score 3):

The RegEx for the above

```
^01[0-9]{9}$
```

`[0-9]{9}` because after 01 the remaining length should be 9 numbers
You can check the site http://regexr.com/ helps out a lot with RegEx especially if you are a beginner like me.

Comment: I doubt it will be working for OP. See [your regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=01%5b0-9%5d%7b9%7d&i=015555555550155555555501555555555015555555550155555555501555555555). It does not check the length at all.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for pointing that out, added the anchors to check the exact length.

Comment: Those are incorrect anchors for validation. Now, you allow a newline symbol at the end of the string. See http://ideone.com/jsgVlE

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried to overcome the RegEx from accepting a newline symbol at the end but to no avail. Is there a way to possible do that only using RegEx?

Comment: [Look here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w(v=vs.110).aspx), you will quickly find it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Is it @"\A01[0-9]{9}\z"?Thanks a bunch for increasing my knowledge in any case :D

Answer (score 1):

if you need regex, try this:

```
^01[0-9]{9}\z
```

Comment: Роман, are you sure? See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e01%5cd%7b9%7d%24&i=01%d9%a1%d9%a2%d9%a3%d9%a4%d9%a5%d9%a6%d9%a7%d9%a8%d9%a9). Also, your regex also allows a newline at the end of the string.

Comment: Nice! 
^01[0-9]{9}$
and add singleline flag

Comment: And here is another "nice": http://ideone.com/jsgVlE. As I said, the regex allows a newline at the end of the input.

Comment: Thanks man, it Worked.

Comment: There is no need for the `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag, there is no dot anywhere in the pattern. You wanted to say "add `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` flag" - that is a good idea as it will [fix the issue with `\d`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e01%5cd%7b9%7d%24&i=01%d9%a1%d9%a2%d9%a3%d9%a4%d9%a5%d9%a6%d9%a7%d9%a8%d9%a9&o=e). Waheed, are you sure you want to allow a string with a newline at the end?

Comment: No definitely not. @Wiktor Stribizew